# Cannot find .pkg file upon building it in terminal / How to convert a .app into a .pkg

Tags: macos, terminal, app-store-connect, mac-app-store, application-loader

Currently I am working on submitting an app to the mac app store. I have gone through several steps but am stuck on the last one. This is as I am trying to build my .app file (made in unity) into a .pkg so I am able to Deliver it to iTunes connect via application loader.

I am entering this command into terminal:

```
productbuild --component GAMENAME.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: DEVELOPER NAME" GAMENAME.pkg
```

For some reason though, after entering even though I don not get an error:

```
Usage: productbuild [--product <requirements-plist>] {--component <component-path> <install-path>} <product-output-path>
    Build product with a self-contained bundle, e.g. for the Mac App Store

Usage: productbuild {--content <content-path>} <product-output-path>
    Build product with in-app content

Usage: productbuild [--product <requirements-plist>] {--root <root-path> <install-path>} <product-output-path>
    Build product with an xcodebuild destination root

Usage: productbuild [options] --distribution <dist-path> [--package-path <search-path>] <product-output-path>
    Build product with a distribution and the packages it references

Usage: productbuild --synthesize [--product <requirements-plist>] {--package <pkg-path>} <distribution-output-path>
    Synthesize and write a distribution from component packages

See productbuild(1) for details.
```

I cannot find the .pkg file that has just been built...
I am not sure if this is because it is hidden somewhere or if I have made a mistake I'm unaware of, but any help would be appreciated

So, in short This question basically is how to make a .app to a .pkg which can be using application loader uploaded to iTunes connect...

EDIT:

Ok as someone suggested I might have gotten the initial terminal command wrong  after all so any suggestions on where I went wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it's an error, as it's telling you that you've entered your command incorrectly — so your `.pkg` was never built.

Comment: ohh ok so would you have any idea were I went wrong @l'L'l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your developer name must be followed by the team ID.

Like - "DEVELOPER NAME (ABC123456)"